# Setting Classpath and Sequentially invoking a jar

Tags: java, bash, shell, classpath

I am trying to write a bash script to automate the work of executing my files for the grader in my class.

```
cd ReflectionJar
export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH:/MicahRamirez/out/artifacts/ReflectionJar/ReflectionJar.jar
java -jar ReflectionJar.jar Notepad ./MicahRamirez/ReflectionJar/otherclasses/Notepad
java -jar ReflectionJar.jar graff ./MicahRamirez/ReflectionJar/otherclasses/graff
java -jar ReflectionJar.jar quark ./MicahRamirez/ReflectionJar/otherclasses/quark
java -jar ReflectionJar.jar yparser         ./MicahRamirez/ReflectionJar/otherclasses/yparser
java -jar ReflectionJar.jar reflectionPackage ./ReflectionJar/MicahRamirez/otherclasses/reflectionPackage
```

Directiory Structure:
[DirectoryStructure Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDQAg.png)

I am currently receiving

```
./reflection.sh: line 4: export: `=': not a valid identifier
./reflection.sh: line 4: export: `./MicahRamirez/out/artifacts/ReflectionJar/ReflectionJar.jar': not a valid identifier
Error: Unable to access jarfile ReflectionJar.jar
...
```

My real roadblock are the first two errors. I have looked at quite a few SO posts to see how I would export the classpath and what I've found doesn't seem to work...

I've tried

```
 export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:./MicahRamirez/out/artifacts/ReflectionJar/ReflectionJar.jar
 export CLASSPATH=./MicahRamirez/out/artifacts/ReflectionJar/ReflectionJar.jar
```

Neither have worked.

Comment: Try `export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/MicahRamirez/out/artifacts/ReflectionJar/ReflectionJar.jar:.`

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the `-jar` option, the classpath is taken from the Manifest file, and the environment variable and/or `-cp` command-line arguments are ignored. See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

> **-jar**
>
> Executes a program encapsulated in a JAR file. The first argument is the name of a JAR file instead of a startup class name. For this option to work, the manifest of the JAR file must contain a line in the form `Main-Class`: *classname*. Here, *classname* identifies the class with the `public static void main(String[] args)` method that serves as your application's starting point.
>
> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and ***other user class path settings are ignored***.

Comment: Oh that's pretty big... I believe my IDE configured the manifest for me, so I would think the correct settings should exist within the jar. I'll double check that, and comment back!